# Perl Storable retrieve an array of Moose Objects

Tags: perl, moose, storable

I tried to store an array of Moose Objects to YAML or JSON.

The saving works very well, but when I try to restore my Objects, they're empty:

```
$VAR1 = bless({}, 'Note');
$VAR2 = bless({}, 'Note');
```

Here is my code:

Note.pm:

```
package Note;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Moose;
use MooseX::Storage;

with Storage('format' => 'JSON', 'io' => 'File');

has 'message' =>(is=> 'rw', isa =>'Str');

1;
```

testNote.pl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use feature 'say';
use Note;
use Storable;
use MooseX::Storage;
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON;

my @container=();

my $obj = Note->new;

$obj->message("firstmessage");
say $obj->message;

push(@container,$obj);

my $obj2 = Note->new;
$obj2->message("secondmessage");

push(@container,$obj2);

my @output=();

for my $counter (0 .. $#container){
    push(@output,$container[$counter]->pack());
}
say "Output packed strings:" ;
for my $counter(0 .. $#output){ 
    say $output[$counter];
}

store \@output, 'saveNotes';

my @Notes=();

my @fin=@{retrieve('saveNotes') };
say "After reading file:";

@Arr=();
for my $counter (0 .. $#fin){
    push(@Arr,Note->unpack($fin[$counter]));
}

say Dumper(@Arr);
```

Hope someone could help :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999875/which-recommended-perl-modules-can-serialize-moose-objects may be of some help.

Comment: Remove your constructor from `Note.pm` - Moose does that for you, and implementing your own could interfere with it. Likewise `$obj->{'message'}= "firstmessage";` should be `$obj->message( $firstmessage );`

Comment: Neil Slate: thx, i will fix this now.
mpaped: i don't have hashref or something like that ;)